# What are the correct terms to use to calculate the average value of running total that is within a procedure?

Tags: mysql, aggregate, cumulative-sum

I'd like to calculate the average value of a running total up to that point of mathematical operations within a procedure.  In particular, I'd like to divide by this average value that has gone into a running total.  However, when I attempt it with the following code (relevant part is bolded below), I get an error that says:

```
invalid use of group function
```

It appears I can't try to calculate an aggregate of an aggregate in MySQL, but I'm not sure how else to do this:

I'd like to create a column that looks like the second one below (expressing the average of values up until that row:

```
conFIP   average_conFIP_for_rows_passed_up_to_that_point
   1            1                  
   3            2                  
   4            2.66                  
   6            3.5
   2            3.2
   5            3.5
```

The relevant part of the code is: `+(accum_cFIP/Count(conFIP))` which is part of

```
SET FI_pit := (((accum_HR*13)+(3*(accum_walks_a+accum_HBP))-(2*accum_K))/accum_ip)+(accum_cFIP/Count(accum_cFIP));


DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS starting_pitcher_stats_FIP1()
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE starting_pitcher_stats_FIP1()
BEGIN
    DECLARE pit_id CHAR (10); 
    DECLARE gdate DATE;
    DECLARE seq INT;
    DECLARE YEARID INT;
    DECLARE TEAM CHAR (3);
    DECLARE HR INT;
    DECLARE walks INT;
    DECLARE HitBP INT;
    DECLARE K INT;
    DECLARE in_pit REAL;
    DECLARE conFIP VARCHAR (255);
    DECLARE accum_ip REAL;
    DECLARE accum_walks_a REAL;
    DECLARE accum_HR REAL;
    DECLARE accum_HBP REAL;
    DECLARE accum_K REAL;
    DECLARE accum_cFIP REAL;
    DECLARE FI_pit REAL;
    DECLARE FIP_g REAL;
    DECLARE prev_year YEAR(4);
    DECLARE end_of_cursor BOOLEAN;

    DECLARE no_table CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '42S02';

    DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR
      SELECT Starting_Pitcher, Game_Date, Game_Number, YEAR_ID, FLD_TEAM_ID, HR_a, walks_a, HBP, strike_outs, innings_pitched, cFIP  
        FROM starting_pitcher_game_log
        ORDER BY Starting_Pitcher, Game_Date, Game_Number;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
      SET end_of_cursor := TRUE;

    SET end_of_cursor := FALSE;  -- reset
    SET prev_year := 0;          -- reset control-break

    OPEN c1;

    fetch_loop: LOOP
      FETCH c1 INTO pit_id, gdate, seq, YEARID, TEAM, HR, walks, HitBP, K, in_pit, conFIP;
      IF end_of_cursor THEN
        LEAVE fetch_loop;
      END IF;

      -- check control-break conditions
      IF YEAR(gdate) != prev_year THEN
        SET accum_ip := 0.0;
        SET accum_walks_a := 0;
        SET accum_HR := 0;
        SET accum_HBP := 0;
        SET accum_K := 0;
        SET accum_cFIP := 0;
        SET prev_year := YEAR(gdate);
      END IF;

      SET accum_ip := accum_ip + in_pit;
      SET accum_walks_a := accum_walks_a + walks;
      SET accum_HR:= accum_HR + HR;
      SET accum_HBP := accum_HBP + HitBP;
      SET accum_K := accum_K + K;
      SET accum_cFIP := accum_cFIP + conFIP;

      IF (accum_ip) = 0 OR (in_pit)=0 THEN  
        SET FI_pit := 0;
        SET FIP_g := 0;
      ELSE
        SET FI_pit := (((accum_HR*13)+(3*(accum_walks_a+accum_HBP))-(2*accum_K))/accum_ip)+conFIP;
        SET FIP_g := (((HR*13)+(3*(walks+hitBP))-(2*K))/in_pit)+conFIP;
      END IF;

      UPDATE starting_pitcher_stats
        SET std_FIP = FI_pit,
         FIP_game = FIP_g
        WHERE Starting_Pitcher = pit_id
          AND Game_Date = gdate
          AND Game_Number = seq;

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE c1;
  END
  $$
  DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Do you have to do this in a procedure?  You should be able to do this in a single query.  Maybe sample data and desired results would help explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: sgeddes, thanks for your help, but I figured out the problem.  I wanted to add a season-to-date statistic field FIP to my table starting_pitcher_stats such that FIP will get updated with the new raw values from every game that go into the formula.  cFIP is a constant.  At first I thought I needed to calc the avg of the running total of cFIP.  But it turns out cFIP is the same for every game within a given year.  So taking the average of a running total of the same constant is that constant.  So, I just use the appropriate cFIP constant for each season. I changed the code above to reflect that.